# Is there a way to save visual studio .net web appilcation so older versions of visual studio would be able to run the project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, webforms, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.5.4 but my teacher is using an older version of visual studio(2010 version) is there a way I can save the project so my teacher would be able to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

you can send him the "project" folder, not the "solution".